# Java issue with input

Tags: java, input

Today I was trying to do a basic exercise and I faced in this problem :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

This is the code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double salary = 0;      // Salary excluded tax
        int tax = 0;            // % of tax
        double taxTot = 0;      // amount of tax
        double totSalary = 0;   // Salary with tax

        System.out.println("Salary, please : "); //Input salary
        salary = input.nextDouble();    

        if (salary <= 15000) {                          // <=15000
            tax = 10;
        } else if (salary>= 40000 && salary < 60000){       // >=40000
            tax = 20;
        } else {                                            // over > 60000
            tax = 30;
        }

        taxTot = salary / 100*tax;
        totSalary = salary - taxTot;
        System.out.println("Your tax is : " + taxTot + " Your salary : " + totSalary);
    }
}
```

Comment: I compiled and ran your program. I got no error when I entered a number. However when entering a letter I got the same error as you, which is not surprising. What is your input?

Comment: i cannot seem to replicate your problem. copy and pasted and it works fine for me.

Comment: What kind of input are you providing when you run this application ?

Comment: Ahh i got it, yeah now I understand the input problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `java.util.InputMismatchException` can get thrown if the next input in the `Scanner` doesn't match the type you're trying to get. Here's an example:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner("hello");
double salary = input.nextDouble();
```

So the problem most probably originates from the `salary = input.nextDouble();` line in your code,
and the cause is that you didn't enter a valid `double`.

To test the behavior of your program, you can write the input in the `Scanner` constructor like I wrote earlier above.
For example you can test by writing this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner("9000");
```

So that `salary` will be 9000, and so since `salary <= 15000`,
`tax` will be set to 10. Change the value to something else to get a different outcome, for example:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner("41000");
```

When you're comfortable with working with a `Scanner`, you can change the fixed string parameter back to `new Scanner(System.in)` and run your complete program.

Comment: I tried as you said but i get error when i try to type a decimal number, i mean if i type 13.548 i get error and the program stop to run. However when i type integer number the program works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Try for example

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
```

There is a difference between 5,0 and 5.0

Comment: thanks a lot. I understand now where was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a read through this it tells you about the [InputMismatchException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html)

Basically, the input in your program doesn't match the Scanner type. So you might get the error because your input is not a double